# Why is my code not executed in the right order?

Tags: java, android

In the code below, can you please explain to me why the block inside the if statement is executed before the method request_user_name() is called? The result of the below code is the following:

I am inside the if statement

I am outside the if statement

request_user_name() is called - OK clicked

```
chatbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(request_user_name())
            {
                System.out.println("I am inside the if statement");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatRoom.class); 
                intent.putExtra("room_name", "room"); 
                intent.putExtra("user_name", name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            System.out.println("I am outside the if statement");
        }
    });




 private Boolean request_user_name() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter Name:");
    final EditText input_filed = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(input_filed);
    final Holder<Boolean> accessChatRoom = new Holder<Boolean>(true); 
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            name = input_filed.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("request_user_name() called - OK clicked");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            System.out.println("request_user_name() called - Cancel clicked");
            accessChatRoom.setValue(false);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
    return accessChatRoom.getValue();
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `request_user_name`?

Comment: Post the whole code please

Comment: request_user_name()   Is returning "true".  Post the code of the Method.

Comment: It isn't executing before `request_user_name()` is being called; it would be easier to provide more context and why you think what you're claiming is true.

Comment: request_user_name() returns true or false depending on the situation. To be short, that method creates an AlertDialog. The user enters his name and click Ok or can click Cancel. If Ok is clicked, the method returns true, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: need to know what's inside request_user_name .

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: `request_user_name` will always return immediately, but the "called and returned true" and "called and returned false" statements are executed asyncronously whenever the user eventually dismisses the dialog.

Comment: imho the easiest fix is to simply move the code from your `if (request_user_name())` block directly into your dialog's `setPositiveButton` `onClick` method (and then make `request_user_name` a `void` since blocking in order to return a value from some asyncronous action isn't really practical). It seems like you expect your dialog to block that method until the dialog is dismissed - it doesn't work that way; `show` returns immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok and works as expected : when you call the function, it prepares a dialog with its 'callbacks' then display it:

```
builder.show();
```

but the code continue **immediately** (show i not a modal blocking call, just display) and code goes to next statement :

```
return accessChatRoom.getValue()
```

value which is at this time as set by the default .

Code has normal behavior : it's a conception problem.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The code in the block isn't executing before the `request_user_name()` method call; the code in the block would not execute at all if `request_user_name()` did not execute and return true. I.E., the print out in the code block is executed only after satisfying the "if" condition (in your case, `request_user_name()`). Try printing out to the console from within the `request_user_name()` method in order to test the order of execution. My guess is your code is not thread-safe inside the `request_user_name()` method. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand yet. 

request_user_name() returns true or false depending on the situation. To be short, that method creates an AlertDialog. The user enters his name and click Ok or can click Cancel. If Ok is clicked, the method returns true, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: In the case that it returns false, does the code block execute?

Comment: In both cases (true or false) request_user_name() is execute after the if statement end scope. You can test my code if you want and put some println() to double check

Comment: See my answer, this behavior is due to event based dispatching of button click behavior.

Comment: The execution is happening on different threads, causing "true" to be returned w/o the onClick callback being dealt with first.

Comment: @NickL has the correct answer.

Comment: @cjbrog actually.. we were both wrong, pirela has the right answer.

Comment: @NickL The only thing I dislike more than being wrong is thinking that I know something that I don't... so thanks! And nice catch pirela.